# What are the deployment options for a Spotfire Visualization?

Tags: spotfire

Once I have a Spotfire visualization developed using a Spotfire client, what are the options for deployment available for me?

Answer (score 2):

You save the Analysis file into library and that makes it available to the users via Web player.
Other option is you save an analysis as a DXP file and send it to the users, but that would required them to have fat client installed just as you have.

Comment: there's also a "diet client" called Spotfire Consumer. it's a thick client a la Spotfire Analyst/Professional, but doesn't offer the ability to create visualizations, only to view and interact with them.